# i have a error 401 with microsoft emotion api in java

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

im using the example code to call the emotions api but i have an error 401 and i cannot identify the error

the result: { "error": { "code": "Unauthorized", "message": "Access denied due to invalid subscription key. Make sure you are subscribed to an API you are trying to call and provide the right key." } }

```
HttpClient cliente = HttpClients.createDefault();

    String key ="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";

    try{
        URIBuilder builder= new URIBuilder("https://api.projectoxford.ai/emotion/v1.0/recognize");
        URI uri = builder.build();
        HttpPost request = new HttpPost(uri);

        request.setHeader("Content-type","application/json");
        request.setHeader("Opc-Apim-Subscription-Key",key);

        StringEntity reqEntity = new StringEntity("\"url\": \"http://am-elsalv-cdn.agilecontents.com/resources/jpg/5/3/1458595472835.jpg\"");
        request.setEntity(reqEntity);

        HttpResponse response = cliente.execute(request);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

        if(entity!=null){
            System.out.println(EntityUtils.toString(entity));
        }

    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
```

Comment: I think there may have been an issue with some accounts in our front-end servers.  Can you try again?

Answer (score 0):

The 401 error is typically shown when you’re using an invalid subscription key to call our APIs. This could happen for a number of reasons:

1. Incorrect key as result of a copy/Paste error when pulling the key from http://www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services/en-us/subscriptions. Additionally, make sure there are no leading or trailing spaces in your key (it doesn’t look like it from your code, but calling out for completeness).
2. If your key was working before and now is no longer working, you could be out of your monthly quota (number of calls) or trying to make calls too quickly for the TPS (transactions per second) supported for your key. You can check the status of your key by going to  the subscriptions page, finding the emotion subscription, and clicking “Show quota”.
3. There is a service interruption currently on-going. If you think this is the case, please let us know  through tickets@cognitive.uservoice.com.

If you’ve tried all of these things and are still experiencing issues, try to make an API call using your subscription key through our testing console. If this still fails, regenerate your key through the subscriptions page by finding the Emotion API, identify the key column, and clicking “Regenerate” under the key that is not working. Note that you’ll have to update all references to your old key as this will completely invalidate it in favor of the newly generated key.

Comment: Please also that note the typo in the request header.  It should be `Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key` (Opc->Ocp)